# P-value of a variance?

Tags: probability

[image]

I know that the p-value is the probability of getting a value more extreme than the one observed given that the null hypothesis is true.
I know that so far we use the z-test and t-test to approximate the mean or calculate the p-value of a mean and the z-test and binomial  to approximate or calculate the p-value of a proportion.But how can we calculate the p-value if the parameter is a variance?

Comment: There is an important distinction between (a) normal tables, which have probabilities in the body of the table and cut-off values in the margins and (b) tables of t, chi-squared, and F distributions, which have cutoff values in the body of the table and probabilities in the margins.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Chi Squared test with (n-1) degrees of freedom. $8.58$ is between $.99$ and $.975$ with a probability equal to the area to the left between $.01$ and $.025$. Because this is not less than $.01$, we cannot reject the null hence answer B.

FYI, variance is the "average" squared distance from the mean.

Comment: Why do you think the critical value here is much more than $20$ rather than much less than $20$?

Comment: @Henry Good point, a smaller $s^2$ would reduce the test statistic yet it would be more likely to be <.04. Do I have this backwards?

Comment: Frequently, there is confusion between 'percentage point' labels in printed tables, and CDF values. // Successful revision (+1).

Answer (score 1):

First, intuition:

(1) *Value of the sample variance:* We can see that $S^2 \approx 0.017,$ which is noticeably below the null value $\sigma_0^2 = 0.04.$ So it seems we may reject $H_0$ in favor of the left-sided alternative. However, variance estimates based on small samples aren't very precise, so we'll reserve judgment until we see the P-values.

(2) *Distribution and value of the test statistic:* The test statistic 
$Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma_0^2} = \frac{20S^2}{.04} = 8.58.$ But under $H_0,$
$Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(20),$ which has $E(Q) = 20.$ Thus 8.58 is in the lower
tail of the null distribution. Again this raises suspicion we might reject $H_0.$

Second, look closely at the distribution of $\mathsf{Chisq}(20)$ for information on the P-value:

*Printed table:* In a printed chi-squared distribution table,
8.58 is between 8.206 and 9.591 (on row $df = 20)$. The respective headers for the relevant columns show "percentage points"
.99 and .975. This means that 99% of the probability in $\mathsf{Chisq}(20)$ is above 8.206 (and 1% below); similarly, 97.5% of the probability is above 9.591
(and 2.5% below). So the P-value is between 0.01 and 0.025.

> Beginning students often confuse (i)
>   "percentage points" in printed tables, which refer to *right-tail* probabilities, one the one hand, with (ii) the CDF, which refers to *left-tail* probabilities, on the other hand. The point of this problem may have been to emphasize the difference.

*R statistical software:* The exact probability below 8.58 can be found using
the chi-squared CDF function `pchisq`. The result is 0.0127. This is smaller than 0.05, so we would reject $H_0$ at the 5% level. But the P-value $0.0127 > 0.01$
so we cannot reject at the 1% level.

```
pchisq(8.58, 20)
## 0.01271886
```

> P-values have come into frequent use with the increasing availability of statistical software. Often, you can't find an exact P-value from a printed table--only bracket its value between two numbers in a table (as above).
>   By contrast, software makes it possible to find exact P-values.

The figure below shows the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(20)$ along with
the observed value $Q$ of the test statistic. The area under the curve to the left of the vertical broken line is the P-value 0.0127.

[image]